# Googlebot receiving missing template error for an existing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, googlebot, missing-template

In the last couple of days, we have started to receive a missing template error when the google bot attempts to access our main home page (welcome/index). I have been staring at this for a couple of hours and know that I am just missing something simple.

```
A ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in welcome#index:
Missing template welcome/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>["*/*;q=0.9"], :locale=>[:en, :en]}
```

But the template does exist (index.html.haml). If it didn't no one could access our home page.

Here is some additional environment information:

```
* REMOTE_ADDR                               : 66.249.72.139
* REMOTE_PORT                               : 56883
* REQUEST_METHOD                            : GET
* REQUEST_URI                               : /

* Parameters: {"controller"=>"welcome", "action"=>"index"}
```

Any insights you have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "Fetch as Googlebot" on Google Webmaster Tools to see if you get a clearer error? http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

Comment: Good suggestion. I just did and it came back successful. However, I can't seem to tell google to use https, which is the protocol that the error occurs on.

Comment: Weird, have you checked, also in Diagnosis, in the crawl errors area to see if you if Google is reporting anything there? Maybe it's passing some parameters.

Comment: Ah, mental sunrise. Though I am not getting any html errors, I am getting chtml errors. Any suggestions on how I can better manage these requests?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error but have no solution yet either. Webmaster Tools "Fetch as Googlebot" works just fine on http and https version. It seems to be a special google bot and not the regular one. The User Agent is "DoCoMo/2.0 N905i(c100;TB;W24H16) (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

Comment: You can represent it locally:
rails s -e production
and write in other terminal:
curl -v -H "Accept: */*; q=0.9" http://127.0.0.1:3000/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to specify the format in your action.

Up until now, I had simply had the following in my index action

```
def index

end
```

Once I inserted a respond_to block

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

I stopped getting the missing template errors.

Comment: Adding this code makes my app respond with an error `HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable`. I don't know if this is what I want yet. (Under Rails 3.0.12)

Answer (score 16):

These errors are coming from the way **GoogleBot formats its `HTTP_ACCEPT` header**. While valid ([see W3 reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)), it adds a `q=0.6` *(last figure may change)* which is used as a separator. Since there is no other media type specified, this `q=0.6` is not necessary and I assume this is why Rails doesn't treat the header correctly.

*(It seems to depend on Rails version. On Rails 3.0.12, it raises a `MissingTemplate` exception.)*

Adding the following code from a previous answer to the concerned controller is not sufficient: it responds with an error `406`.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

To make this work under Rails 3.0.12 and **have something returned to the GoogleBot** (better than a `406` error), you need to add this code which sets the request's format to `html` as soon a `*/*;q=0.6`-like `HTTP_ACCEPT` is detected (Rails load the header value into `request.format`).

```
# If the request 'HTTP_ACCEPT' header indicates a '*/*;q=0.6' format,
# we set the format to :html.
# This is necessary for GoogleBot which perform its requests with '*/*;q=0.6'
# or similar HTTP_ACCEPT headers.
if request.format.to_s =~ %r%\*\/\*%
  request.format = :html
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

**While working, this solution needs the code to be added to any controller action you want to be indexed by the GoogleBot, what is really not DRY!**

**To fix this issue once for all, I implemented a small Rack middleware which does even better**: it checks the request's `HTTP_ACCEPT` header, and will replace any header matching `*/*;q=0.6` *(the figures can vary)* by the common `*/*`. This is even better because since the `q=0.6` has no meaning if it is not followed by another media type, this change of the header doesn't change its meaning. **We don't force Rails into any given format, we just tell it any will do in a way it can understand.**

You can find the middleware, the loading initializer and an integration test in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2590040/93cb2faca1ba5ead73222e74ca11790e3efb22de).

Gem version here:
https://github.com/ouvrages/rails_fix_google_bot_accept

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. This is far better than a `406`.

Comment: I made a gem based on your gist: https://github.com/ouvrages/rails_fix_google_bot_accept

Comment: @MichaëlWitrant Thanks for making it a gem!

Comment: Looks like Rails 4 handles the `q` parameter correctly, at least from my limited testing.

Answer (score 6):

I am also getting the same, I did some investigation and came to the conclusion it is a 'bug' in Rails. `*/*;q=0.9` is the value of the HTTP accept parameter. I'm not exactly sure what is going on, but in Rails 3.0 this works. In Rails 3.1 it returns a 500 response, and in Rails 3.2 it returns a 406 response.

**Update:**

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4127) regarding this issue. One workaround is to set this new option in Rails 3.1:

```
config.action_dispatch.ignore_accept_header = true
```

However... if you serve any pages other than HTML you'll need to rely on the extension to denote the type (e.g. `/users/1.json`) instead of accept headers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am running 3.0.7. So this may not apply to my case.

Answer (score 1):

the interesting part in the error that you posted is `:formats=>["*/*;q=0.9"]`

the rails-app tries to find a template for the format `"*/*;q=0.9"` which is not going to work.

i guess that google is somehow using this as a format query parameter like `welcome?format=*/*;q=0.9`

afaik latest rails versions will just render a 406 in those cases.

Comment: Isn't that coming from the accept-header, saying that it will accept any type of file?

Comment: i think that it must somehow be interpreted as a format by your rails application. otherwise there is no reason why it throws an error on this subject.

Comment: You can represent it locally: rails s -e production and write in other terminal: curl -v -H "Accept: /; q=0.9" 127.0.0.1:3000