# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index - Google Crawler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I'm experiencing this error when I launch Google Crawler on the site:

**Error message:**

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>["image/*"],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/releases/32/app/views" *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.10/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-2.1.4/app/views"

**Research on SO:**

I took note of these 3 related problems:
[ActionView::MissingTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134739/actionviewmissingtemplate) -> I'm not using HAML

[ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561000/actionviewmissingtemplate-missing-template) -> Not related

[Googlebot receiving missing template error for an existing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881756/googlebot-receiving-missing-template-error-for-an-existing-template/10027418#10027418) -> Tried the gem "rails_fix_google_bot_accept" no difference.

**More Details:**

**Errbit says possible errors:**
88.4%

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>["image/*"],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/releases/30/app/views" *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.10/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-2.1.4/app/views"

7.4%

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>[:css],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/releases/30/app/views" *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.10/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-2.1.4/app/views"

2.5%

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>["image/*"],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/releases/32/app/views" *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.10/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-2.1.4/app/views"

1.7%

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template home/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>["image/*"],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/releases/24/app/views" *
>   "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.0.10/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/custodir/apps/default/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-2.1.4/app/views"

**Full Backtrace:**
https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/a59e134a98b4d5bc1438

**HTTP_ACCEPT:**
image/*

**HTTP_USER_AGENT:**
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 Google favicon

**Parameters:**

{
  "action" => "index",
  "controller" => "home"
}

**Update 1: Added HomeController Index**

```
  def index
    @interest_groups = InterestGroup.all.sort_by &:position || []                              # Category blocks
    @special_interest_groups = SpecialInterestGroup.all || []               # Student block(s)
    @hot_jobs = HotJob.all(api_params_for_user) || []                       # Hot Jobs
    @jobs_for_you = Job.jobs_for_you(api_params_for_user) || []             # Jobs for you
    @applications = []

    if current_user
      @applications = Application.all_for_user_with_token(current_user.token).select{|a| a.visible?} # Applications
      @user = current_user
      @user.fetch_sap_data!
    end

    if params[:status] && params[:status] == '404'
      @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_404")
      @errors_long = I18n.t("home.errors.error_404_long")
      @errors_extra = I18n.t("home.errors.error_404_extra")
    elsif params[:status]  && params[:status] == '422'
      @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_422")
    elsif params[:status]  && params[:status] == '500'
      @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_500")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have this template?

Comment: What makes me puzzle is the `image/*` which should for normal be html so the template isn't found because there is no file extension assigned to this type.

Comment: @BroiSatse please explain what you mean with template? Under the Views/home I have _application_group.html.erb and _hot_jobs.html.erb and index.html.erb.

Comment: @davidb I saw Google favicon, the website favicon is formed as:  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>

Comment: I'm going to make a linked topic on Webmasters Stack Exchange maybe they can help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing template blogs/index on Ruby on Rails project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557010/missing-template-blogs-index-on-ruby-on-rails-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answers:

Bots are triggering page www.example.com/status=500 which was a page that triggered my HTTP 500 errors.

I found a better way of implementing my error pages now and this resolved my problem:

http://makandracards.com/makandra/12807-custom-error-pages-in-rails-3-2